# Movie where medical students try to revive Dracula

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire, dracula

A while ago i saw part of a movie where some medical students find Dracula's corpse and try to revive him. Anyone know the movie? If you need more info, there was also a strange priest trying to catch them and re-kill Dracula. I never got to finish it and it was intriguing and i would like to see it. Does anyone know the movie title?

Comment: How long ago was 'a while ago'?  1 year, 10 years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Dracula II: Ascension](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0336325/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl).

The sequel to [Dracula 2000](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0219653/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), it involves several medical students tasked with performing an autopsy on a charred body that they come to believe is a vampire.

There is also Father Uffizi, who hunts vampires.  Father Uffizi is searching for the first vampire, Dracula, who just so happens to be the charred victim revived by the hapless medical students.

Comment: I liked your answer more because while ghoppe gave more background, your answer felt more relevant and to the point.

Comment: @TheLollipopGuildmaster Thanks, I'm glad my answer was helpful!  I contemplated deleting it after seeing that ghoppe posted his answer while I was still composing mine; I'm glad I left it.

Answer (score 10):

### [Dracula II: Ascension](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0336325/)

> Father Uffizi [Jason Scott Lee] hunts vampires. He travels the world to behead them with his bullwhip, but his ultimate goal is to find the first vampire, Dracula (revealed as Judas Iscariot in Dracula 2000), absolve Dracula's sins against Jesus, set his soul free, and end his unholy existence. So, when Dracula's charred body turns up in the New Orleans morgue, Uffizi heads there. Medical students, Liz Blaine [Diane Neal] and Luke [Jason London] are charged with autopsying the body.